# tensorflow function tf.gfile.Glob cannot read files that are in a folder consisting of more than 4 files

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow `tfRecord` to input my data. I find that if the number of `tfRecord` shards are more than 4, the function

```
tf.gfile.Glob(tf_record_pattern)
```

always fails when it tries to get the list of files that match the given pattern. There is an error

> `Error in '/usr/bin/python2.7': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00000000013d8d20`

when it exits from failure. I am wondering how many `tfRecord` shards I can make at most. I don't see any upper bound of this in any instructions. For large dataset as `ImageNet`, I guess 4 shards shouldn't be enough. Or else, is it a bug in tensorflow or python? This problem happens all the times and I am eager to find an answer.

Comment: I am using tfRecords too (with more than 4 shards) but I didn't see that happen. However, I did see this error before. See if [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6968#issuecomment-279060156) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. The solution in this discussion works.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8717

```
sudo apt-get install google-perftools
export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libtcmalloc.so.4"
```